# Fedora 25 doesn't allow me to set a Compose Key

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, compose-key

On Fedora 24, setting a compose key was easy, the keyboard shortcuts setting was there to help.

I upgraded to Fedora 25 and now that setting changed and I can't set a compose key anymore.

Here is what it now looks like:

[image: Fedora 25 missing Compose Key (French interface)]

Is there a way to set it anyway? Even using the terminal.

PS: Please create [fedora25](/questions/tagged/fedora25) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the compose key you want to set. You can get the list with the command:

```
$ grep "compose" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

Then, in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` (Exact file may vary), add the line:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "<compose-key-code>"
```

in the `InputClass` section.

Example for me:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "ch"
        Option "XkbVariant" "fr"
        Option "XkbOptions" "compose:rctrl"
EndSection
```

Reboot (or at least `# pkill X`) is required.

[Source](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-x-server-configuration.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can set it with the gnome-tweak-tool. It is found under the typing tweaks. The gnome-tweak-tool is easily installed with the gnome-software application.

Comment: It is found under `Typing` => `Position of Compose Key`.
I would recommend `Right Alt` if you have the physical key.
I can't believe this is not available in standard Gnome though.

Answer (score 0):

. Go to gnome `tweak` tool

. Then select `typing` left menu

. Expand `Position of Compose Key` and select the key that best suites you. it was `right Alt` in my older fedora